# Maximum temp GTX780m Alienware

Tags: graphics, max, temperature

I have an alienware 17 with an GTX780m.
And im currently mining feathercoins.
But I noticed that my gpu temperature went to 78 degrees.
Is this dangerous?

Greetz Vinnie

Answer (score 0):

78 degress celsius? (remember some people is used to fahrenheit)

Anyway that you not burn your gpu but can shorten its life time.
For any eletronics the best option is to keep temperature constant.

You can try to install fans or buy a case with fans like this.
[case whit 6 fans](http://www.google.com.br/imgres?imgurl=http://bimg1.mlstatic.com/gabinete-sentey-arvina-vermelho_MLB-F-3154340240_092012.jpg&imgrefurl=http://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-512899028-gabinete-sentey-arvina-vermelhor28000-em-mos-_JM&h=800&w=1200&sz=110&tbnid=PK_Y3p2idb0NbM%3a&tbnh=90&tbnw=135&zoom=1&usg=__MvsUNoG5qoLdRdgatIAk0THZSJA=&docid=PmlW4k5dYlRFgM&sa=X&ei=G2-YUsWtI4PZkQfx6IBw&ved=0CFUQ9QEwBQ)

Comment: It is 78 degrees celsius.
I didnt asked my question with enough information.

I'm using a Alienware m17x R4 Laptop.
I can't use speedfan to speed up the fans or with MSI Afterburner.

If I mine, the temperature is constant.

Comment: I owned a 17" gamer laptop and you need to be cautious where do you put that thing. The important thing is not putting it over bed or pillows that ill for sure block the air entrances. There are laptop tables with fans, I strongly suggest you to buy one.